# Read string from multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to set a value for a string just once:
example

```
string ItemID= "1";
```

And then to use this string from multiple threads, for creating a query in sql server.
Example:

#### Thread 1

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from inventory where itemid='"+ ItemID +"'");
```

#### Thread 2

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from inventory where itemid='"+ ItemID +"'");
```

and so on...

Is this method right? Reading a string from multiple threads is it safe? Is there any other way for what i want to achieve?

Comment: You can use a `string` like you're suggesting just fine for multiple threads. You can even change the value of the string as string updates are atomic - however, you can't be sure which value your threads might use so it's best not to change the value of the string. It would be awesome to see more of your code to actually see if there's a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Also, don't build SQL statements like `"Select * from inventory where itemid='"+ ItemID +"'"`. It's a [SQL Injection Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly . you want a way to work with property in multi thread
option 1:

```
 var lockObject = new object();
    private string _itemId;
    public string ItemId
    {
        get
        {
            
                return _itemId;
            
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_itemId))
            {
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_itemId))
                    {
                        _itemId = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

option 2 :

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    private string _itemId;
    public string ItemId
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_itemId))
            {
                _semaphore.Wait();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_itemId))
                {
                    _itemId = value;
                }
                _semaphore.Release();

            }

        }
```